# Quitar posiciónes de una array

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Estoy intentando realizar un ejercicio de práctica de array en Java, básicamente el programa me pide que elija una ciudad que quiero eliminar de mi array, pero esta eliminación debe efectuarse desplazando los elementos posteriores una posición hacia el inicio y luego mostrar de nuevo la lista de ciudades.

Hasta ahora he conseguido lo siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    String ciudades[] = { "Albacete", "Barcelona", "Valencia", "Segovia", "Madrid", "Pamplona", "Orense",
            "Tarragona", "Cuenca", "Granada" };

    int num_ciudad = 0;

    int ciudades_length = ciudades.length - 1;

    do {

        System.out.println("Ciudades :");
        for (int i = 0; i < ciudades.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + " - " + ciudades[i]); //Aquí muestro la lista de ciudades
        }

        System.out.println("Elige una ciudad :");
        num_ciudad = teclado.nextInt(); //Aquí elijo la ciudad a eliminar

        if (num_ciudad <= 0 || num_ciudad > ciudades.length) {
            System.out.println("Entrada incorrecta.");
        } else {
            for (int i = ciudades_length; i < ciudades.length - 1; i++) {
                //Aquí es es dónde no sé cómo proceder...
            }
        }
    }

    while (!(ciudades.length < 1));

    System.out.println("No quedan ciudades por eliminar"); //Fin del programa

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bueno podría sugerirte que cambiemos de usar un arreglo a una Lista, pero eso ya te lo dejo a ti.*

Tomando tu Código como base para que puedas "eliminar" el elemento del arreglo, vamos a desplazar todos los elementos que estén detrás una posición adelante, y al último vamos a asignarle el valor "null", debido a que la longitud de tu arreglo de String[] siempre va ser el mismo, en este caso 10, por lo tanto en tu arreglo en realidad siempre va existir 10 elementos, solo que vamos a considerar al elemento eliminado siempre y cuando sea igual a null.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    String ciudades[] = { "Albacete", "Barcelona", "Valencia", "Segovia", "Madrid", "Pamplona", "Orense",
            "Tarragona", "Cuenca", "Granada" };

    int num_ciudad = 0;

    int iUltimoValorDeCiudades = -1;

    do {
        iUltimoValorDeCiudades = -1; // ini siempre en -1 -> va indicar que todo fue eliminado y saldrá del While
        System.out.println("Ciudades :");
        for (int i = 0; i < ciudades.length; i++) {
            // acá agregamos un if, sí el valor es diferente de nulo entonces imprimimos, recuerda que nulo significa que ya fue eliminado
            if(ciudades[i] != null) {
              System.out.println((i + 1) + " - " + ciudades[i]); //Aquí muestro la lista de ciudades
              iUltimoValorDeCiudades = i; // guardamos el ultimo valor
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Elige una ciudad :");
        num_ciudad = teclado.nextInt(); // Aquí elijo la ciudad a eliminar

        if (num_ciudad <= 0 || num_ciudad > iUltimoValorDeCiudades) {
            System.out.println("Entrada incorrecta.");
        } else {
            // Ojo acá pongo (num_ciudad - 1) ya que tu estas mostrando la posición +1 en consola.
            for (int i = (num_ciudad - 1) ; i < iUltimoValorDeCiudades + 1; i++) {
                // Aquí es es dónde no sé cómo proceder...
                // Corremos todo una posición y al último ponemos null.
                // Ten cuidado de no salirte del rango del arreglo.
                if(i < ( ciudades.length - 1) )
                   ciudades[i] = ciudades[i + 1];
                else 
                   ciudades[i] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    // acá cambiamos la condición del while.
    while (iUltimoValorDeCiudades > 0);

    System.out.println("No quedan ciudades por eliminar"); //Fin del programa

}
```

Revisa los comentarios que te he dejado en el código donde trato de explicarte un poco más el porque.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la función `findIndex(miArray, valorBuscado)` te devolverá el índice de la ciudad buscada. tras conseguir el indice tendrás que borrarla del array (con la función `miArray = ArrayUtils.remove(miArray, Indice);` y para volver a reordenarla deberías utilizar : `Arrays.sort(miArray);`

Un saludo.